# How to fetch Source Configuration from AnthillPro programatically?

Tags: continuous-integration, anthill

I went through the REST API doc of AnthillPro but couldn't find anything useful on fetching source configuration for a workflow.

What I need exactly is the code repository(svn/git) for the workflow. In anthillPro, it can be seen/edited from Administration >> Folder >> Project >> Build >> SourceConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the proper plugin ? Use this site to download what you need -
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugins/anthillpro/

I use AHP 5, so after installing the plugins you should do the followings:

1. Check to see if plugin installed and all the steps and details - you should see them in

System -> Server -> Plugins

2. Then you should create a new repository from:

System -> Project support -> Repositories

3. Then add steps to a job, that is assigned to the workflow you have, from:

Administration -> Job -> "Add step icon"

From the steps popup:

Repositories -> source -> GIT -> ALL THE AVAILABLE STEPS

Option 2 (never did that myself) -
Add a shell script/ batch as a step and write your own code to fetch you desired code

Enjoy,
Eli